# Simple array lookup

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array, $persons
When I execute: `print_r($persons)` I get:

```
(
[0] => 30131
[1] => 29763
)
```

The two five-digit numbers are IDs for two posts in a CPT called people

How do I iterate through the array and print the title of each post?

My best guess returns nothing:

```
            foreach( $persons as $person ):
                $title = get_the_title( $person->ID );
                $peopleout .= $title . ', ' ;
            endforeach;
            echo $peopleout
```

Comment: It should just be `get_the_title($person)` judging from your first snippet. `$person` would not be an object in this case, so `$person->ID` would be incorrect. Other then that, your code looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your first snippet, `$person` inside your loop is a single value, not an object.

That means you should change the `$title =` lines to this:

```
$title = get_the_title($person);
```

Also, you will currently be adding an extra comma at the end of the string. To resolve this, I would add the title to an array, then `implode` that array  to echo the values. That would look like this;

```
$peopleout = [];
foreach( $persons as $person ):
    $peopleout[] = get_the_title($person);
endforeach;
echo implode(", ", $peopleout);
```

Comment: Thanks Grumpy! Fantastic answer and you also answered my next issue. Cheers.

Comment: @RichardU Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

`$person` is no object, so keep it plain as it contains the ID.

```
$title = get_the_title($person);
```

Just for fun you can do all of this as a one-liner.

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(fn($id) => get_the_title($id), $persons));
```